# Node.js promises and bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm new into Promises.

I use Bookshelf.js as ORM.

I fetch a number of webpages, get person info (about actors) from those pages and add them into my database if they don't exist.

But there's a problem, even though `console.log(name)` returns actor names in the right order, my query checks for only one actor, the latest one, which is 9.

What's wrong here?

```
var entities = require("entities");
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

// create promisified version of request()
function requestPromise(options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(options, function (err, resp, body) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

var person = require('./models').person;


app.get('/fetch', function (req, res) {
  var promises = [];
  var headers = {
    'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent'],
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  };
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    promises.push(requestPromise({url: "http://www.example.com/person/" + i + "/personname.html", headers: headers}));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(function (data) {
    // iterate through all the data here
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if ($ = cheerio.load(data[i])) {
        var links = $("#container");
        var name = links.find('span[itemprop="name"]').html(); // name
        if (name == null) {
          console.log("null name returned, do nothing");
        } else {
          name = entities.decodeHTML(name);
          console.log(name); // returns names in the right order
          // does this person exist in the database?
          person.where('id', i).fetch().then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
              console.log(i + "exists");
            } else {
              console.log(i + " doesn't exist"); 
              // returns "9 doesn't exists" 9 times instead of
              // checking each ID individually, why?
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        console.log("can't open");
      }
    }
  }, function (err) {
    // error occurred here
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

EDIT #2

Now the order is broken and my ID's aren't the same with the site's I fetch data from. I see ID's like 11 and 13 even though I iterate from 1 to 5 and it seems to overrule something since it adds duplicate entries.

Here's what I'm trying to do in a nutshell. "Visit these urls in order and add the data you fetch (e.g. names) in the same order (id1 = name1; id2 = name2, etc) to the database".

```
app.get('/fetch', function (req, res) {
  var promises = [];
  var headers = {
    'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent'],
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  };
  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    promises.push(requestPromise({url: "http://example.com/person/ + i + "/personname.html", headers: headers}));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(function (data) {
    // iterate through all the data here
    data.forEach(function (item, i) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(item);
      var name = $("#container span[itemprop='name']").text();
      if (!name) {
        console.log("null name returned, do nothing");
      } else {
        // name exists
        person.where('id', i).fetch({require: true}).then(function (p) {
          console.log(i + " exists");
        }).catch(function () {
          console.log(i + " does not exist");
          new person({id: i, name: name}).save(null, {method: 'insert'}).then(function () {
            console.log("success" + i);
          });
        });
      }
    }, function (err) {
      // error occurred here
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your code through jshint, you will see a warning that says

> Don't make functions within a loop.

In this piece of code the callback inside `then` does not run in sync with the enclosing `for` loop. It runs whenever the database has fetched your result.

```
person.where('id', i).fetch().then(function (result) {
  if (result) {
    console.log(i + "exists");
  } else {
    console.log(i + " doesn't exist"); 
  }
});
```

Therefore, when that callback runs eventually, the loop has long finished. Your callback function holds a reference to the loop counter `i` - which, by now, has the value 9.

It's better to use a function that accepts a parameter than to refer to a loop counter.

Luckily node makes this easy, you can use the `forEach` array function:

```
data.forEach(function (item, i) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(item);
  var name = $("#container span[itemprop='name']").text();

  if (!name) {
    console.log("null name returned, do nothing");
  } else {
    console.log("successfully scraped name: " + name);

    person.where('id', i).fetch({require: true}).then(function (p) {
      console.log(i + " exists");
    }).catch(function () {
      console.log(i + " does not exist");
    });
  }
});
```

Note that you can make Bookshelf.js throw instead of silently passing over non-existing records with `{require: true}`.

---

More generally speaking, I don't see a real connection between scraping the name from a website and retrieving a model from the database. These two things should probably be done in separate functions that each return an individual promise for the respective thing. That way, requests to the database can run in parallel with requests to the web server.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I'm using the same ID's on my db with that website, so I need to keep them consistent for now.

Comment: You can still do both - what I am saying is that this code is needlessly serializing them (the requests!) here. Output order is a different matter. Let's assume the web requests take 70 ms each and the database requests take 30 ms each. By running the database requests one by one after each web request you ramp up the time to completion to 100 ms each. It could be done in 70 ms each by separating web and database requests.

Comment: Okay, one more question. Could you please check my edit #2? Even If I loop from 1 to 5, records aren't being added in the right order (i = id) and I see numbers like 11 and 13 in the db.

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that would explain IDs showing up that you did not define. I'm afraid you will have to debug that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a closure for `person.where('id', i).fetch()`.

also use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) instead of hand rolling [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).